# Will recursive_mutex deadlock when locked by 2 threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

std::recursive_mutex won't deadlock when the *same* thread locks it multiple times.

Will it deadlock when *multiple* threads lock it multiple times?

Comment: Mutexes do not deadlock -- poorly written threads which are co-operating via a mutex might deadlock one another.  Do you mean block?  As in “If a recursive mutex is held by one thread, will a second thread attempting to lock that mutex block”?  If so, yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Will it deadlock when multiple threads lock it multiple times?

**That cannot happen.**

By *definition* a [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) is locked by at most one thread. And a [`std::recursive_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex) is some kind of mutex. Otherwise it does not comply to its goal of [mutual exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion), since it should be some kind of [Mutex concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Mutex).

So another thread is not even allowed to lock it a single time. When it does, that other thread stays blocked (till the lock is released - as many times as it was recursively locked).

Comment: The query wasn't about `mutex`; it was about `recursive_mutex`. WIll a `recursive_mutex` deadlock if locked by multiple threads?

Comment: Of course, otherwise it won't work as a mutex. I added some link to documentation

Comment: @SSteven A `recursive_mutex` *is* a `mutex`. It just has the extra property that the thread having it locked can lock it again without deadlocking.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, does `recursive_mutex` derive from `mutex`?

Comment: @SSteven Inherit? No (at least, if it does then that's an implementation detail). But it satisfies the [Mutex concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Mutex). Why don't you just read [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex) yourself?

Answer (score 2):

FYI, here is a simplistic implementation of a recursive mutex:

```
static const std::thread_id NO_THREAD;

class recursive_mutex {
public:

    void lock() {
        auto me = std::this_thread::get_id();
        if (owner != me) {
            mtx.lock();
            owner = me;
            assert(count == 0);
        }
        count++;
    }

    void unlock() {
        auto me = std::this_thread::get_id();
        assert(owner == me);
        assert(count > 0);
        count--;
        if (count == 0) {
            owner = NO_THREAD;
            mtx.unlock();
        }
    }

private:
    std::mutex      mtx;
    std::thread::id owner;
    unsigned        count{0};
};
```